# How to use Flutter " package:flutter_android/android_telephony.dart' "?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

I wanted the feature of ,

> import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

in flutter, and according to pub.dev

> package:flutter_android/android_telephony.dart

can do the same function, but i'm unable to make it work. Can someone please help ?

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

switch (info.getSubtype()) {
  case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
    return "2G"; // ~ 50-100 kbps
  case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
    return "3G"; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
  case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
    return "4G"; // ~ 10+ Mbps
  case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
    return "unknown"; // is connected but cannot tell the speed
  default:
    return "none";
}
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Please post a code snippet to determine the exact issue.

Comment: That part of the plugin looks like a stub.

Comment: I am not even able to use the package ! there is not enough documentation about this package.